# TestNG test passes, but fails when run via Ant even though build succeeds

Tags: ant, testng

I have a TestNG test that works as expected when run as TestNG Suite in Eclipse, but fails when run via TestNG Ant Task (also via Eclipse).  The same test also fails when I run Ant via the command line. The build succeeds, but the test fails with the message:

org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'homepage.title' is required by @Test on method login but has not been marked @Optional or defined

The parameter is defined correctly in my TestNG.xml, and as I mentioned, the same test passes if I run via "Run as TestNG Suite"

Thanks in advance!  I hope to be able to help others out as well!

Comment: It would really help to post example of your test method and Ant target.

Comment: yeah, sorry.  I was getting to that and then was distracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you define a parameter for the test but not specify a value for it.

```
@Test
public void myTest(String myParameter){
}
```

There are several ways to solve this.
One would be to specify Parameter annotation and pass parameter in either testng.xml or in through jvm arg:

```
@Test
@Parameters({"myParameter"})
public void myTest(String myParameter){
}
```

testng.xml file:

```
<suite>
    <test>
         <parameter name="myParameter" value="myValue" />
         <classes>
              <class name="org.example.MyTestClass" />
         </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

or in build.xml file specify jvmarg property:

```
<testng>
   <jvmarg value="-DmyParameter=myValue" />
   <!-- ... -->
</testng>
```

The other way, that is suggested by the TestNG, is to annotate parameter with @Optional:

```
@Test
@Parameters({"myParameter"})
public void myTest(@Optional("myValue") String myParameter){
}
```

On the additional note, the reason why your build might be passing is whether you tell Ant to fail the build on the test failure. In this case if the build compiles, but there is a test failed, the build will still report "Succeeded" result:

```
<testng haltonfailure="true">
   <!-- ... -->
</testng>
```

The default value for `haltonfailure` property is "false".

Please refer to [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) for more information on [parameters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters) and how to use [TestNG with Ant](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html).

Comment: Specifying the jvmarg in build.xml did the trick.  I was already using the parameter annotation on my test method, and specifying the value in testng.xml.  Interestingly that works fine for TestNG on its own, but Ant still wants me to supply the jvmarg.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Strange. Usually having `@Parameters` annotation and specifying parameter in testng.xml is sufficient. Are you also passing testng.xml for Ant target to run tests in 'xmlfileset' element?

Comment: yep, got it working properly now.  Thanks again... spent a couple days getting frameworks wired up and I haven't even written any tests yet!